# Transforming Video Pixel Map

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

one of the lectures I am taking right now has recorded all sessions but the whole video of some lectures is weirdly shifted. An example screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how transform a whole video (90 minutes) (not just a single image) to be in the right format? Maybe using ffmpeg?

The efficiency is important here, I could surely write a script that does that for one image but this is about ~ 10 lectures each 90 minutes.

It is not important that the color is shifted differently. The black and white content is the most important one.

Best,
Moritz

Comment: See [Fix distorted mp4 files](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29282/fix-distorted-mp4-files) which appears to also have distorted slides from the same university or maybe the same lecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes same university possibly same lecture. Didn't look on StackExchange yet.